# Managing Tab Click Event through jQuery and Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, repeater

I have a repeater which displays and data bind the source of tab links. Here is the code:

```
protected void rptTab_ItemBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Item i = e.Item.DataItem as Item;
        Link hlTabLink = e.Item.FindControl("hlTabLink") as Link;
        hlTabLink.Target = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(i);
        hlTabLink.DataSource = i.Paths.FullPath;
        hlTabLink.Field = "Title";
    }
}
```

Now this is my markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTab" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptTab_ItemBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li id= "liTabTest" runat = "server">
                    <a>
                        <sc:Link ID = "hlTabLink" Field = "scTabLink" onclick = "TabClick()" runat ="server"></sc:Link>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

And this is the jQuery which is adding CSS class dynamically based on which item is selected:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    init();
});

function init() {
    $("ul#Tab-labels li").removeClass("tab-label TabbedPanelsTabSelected");
    $("ul#Tab-labels li:first").addClass("tab-label TabbedPanelsTabSelected");
};

function TabClick() {
    alert('test');
};
```

Now you can see that I am displaying the CSS file based on the index of the tab. I also have to add the click event in that jQuery. So there are basically two things that I am confused:

- My click event in jQuery is not getting called :(
- From jQuery I have to know in the click event that which page it has
  to go through? So that I have to get from codebehind or what? Like a
  hidden field and store the tab pages in that, then fetch out from
  jQuery.

How should I resolve this? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `sc:Link`, change the bind method to `onClientClick` for `onclick = "TabClick()"`. `OnClick` is for the postback server method.

BTW, what is the `sc` prefix? Is there a user control you are adding to the page?

Comment: sc stands for Sitecore. Thanks!

Comment: Did this work? If, so please mark as answer. If not, how else can I help?

Comment: Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632660/add-css-class-through-a-repeater

Comment: I have another question, if you can help me on that.